# How to process GCM notifications, launching activity per alert without erasing other alerts

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I guess it is hard to explain just by reading the title of this question.  I am coding an app that gets ambient factors alerts (temperature, etc) sent by a known server to GCM, and then GCM sends it back to the phone. The whole GCM works well.  The problem is when notifications arrive. It is thought to send notifications to the phone when an alert happens (a trigger). Then clicking on the alert launches the activity to display the alert.  That is OK, but if there is 2 or more alerts on waiting to be clicked, it will only process one, ignoring the rest ("mensaje"). This is how my notification inside a class that extends `extends GcmListenerService` looks like.

```
   public static void showAlerts(Context context, String mensaje)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("mensaje", mensaje);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Random r = new Random();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, r.nextInt(),
            notificationIntent, 0);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Nueva alerta recibida")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.termometrorojo)
            .setNumber(UtilidadesGCM.num_notificaciones++)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Then in MainActivity, I have the code to process this, and open the activity to display the alert

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String nuevaAlerta = intent.getExtras().getString("mensaje");
        procesaAlerta(nuevaAlerta);

        //mDisplay.append(nuevaAlerta + "\n");
    }
};



public void procesaAlerta (String alerta)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alertas.class);
    intent.putExtra("mensaje" , alerta);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The Alertas class will parse the message fine and display it in its activity, but will only do that once. If there are more than 2 alerts stacked to be read, it only process one. If there is one, it works ok.  Sorry if I odn't explain better, but it hard not showing all the code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with writing this line

```
notificationManager.notify( new Random().nextInt(), notification);
```

instead of

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Your notification id is every time same so your last notification only work. Every new notification id is replaced by id 0. So i use random id instead of fixed id 0. I think above code will work for you